# Sitecore Content Management warm up issue in 8.2 update 7 website

Tags: sitecore-client, content-management

We have an issue whenever we restore production DBs to QA/local environment our Content management doesn't come up though content delivery is all fine

**What I did so far:**
Earlier we noticed that our Core/EventQueue table had lots of entries so we reduced agent's time to 4 hours and can see the effect(Not too many rows) but still it's failing. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restoring db from production to your local environment, clean EventQueue and History tables in both `core` and `master` databases.

Otherwise, your local instance will try to process every single entry from those tables at startup and that will pretty much make it unresponsive if you have plenty of entries there.

Comment: I'm still seeing this issue 

I had below entries -- I went to database and deleted those still it couldn't warm up cm instance

core/EventQues
20k+
core/History
47

master/EventQues
6k+
master/History
9 million

Comment: @Marek.Musielak check this, tried suggested fix but no luck

Comment: @marek.musielak any other workaround or something to try ?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the steps that you could take are:

- Compare the System specs of PRD with QA and update if required. RAM, Number of CPU cores along with hard disk capacity
- Clear the Event Queue and History tables
- Assuming you are using XP, check if features like Content Testing, Path Analyzer are used in the Project. If not, disable them
- There may be a lot of content users in the PRD, you may decide to clear them
- Check the Contact Lists and Segmented Lists in the Marketing Control Panel. If the number is high, you may want to remove some
- Check the scheduled jobs and tasks running. You may want not want to run them in QA/local
- Check the Sitecore logs if there are any errors there

Comment: @sumit.upadhay 

it fails in Prod too whenever we do Blue/Green deployment So I'm not sure about these steps

Comment: @sumit.upadhay The only thing I could try was clearing EventQueue and History tables but that didn't solve the problem Though I noticed it took sometime in warm up , anything to look for that

Comment: Do you see anything in the logs?

Comment: Nope, nothing related

Comment: are you trying from within the server or from outside?

Comment: Actually we've octopus release where we've a step for Sitecore 8.2 Vanilla installation then we've a PS Script to  warmup CM instance